# How can I prove it is a martingale when there is a jump process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $N_t$ be a Possion process, $M_t=N_t - \lambda t$ we can easily show that $M_t$ is a martingale.

Now $\int_0^t\Phi_udM_u=.....=\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}\Phi_{\tau_i}-\lambda\int_0^t \Phi(u)du $

$\tau_i$ is jumps time of the poisson process $N_t$.

The question is how to prove $\int_0^t\Phi_udM_u$ is a martingale?? You may give any extra conditions to $\Phi$ if needed. (I am more interested in the ideas to cope with this question instead of this question itself.)

Comment: Hi I think you should add more inforamtions about properties of $\Phi$ if you want to get an answer. Best regards

Comment: If we want to *easily show that $M_t$ is a martingale*, we might better define it as $M_t=N_t-\lambda t$.

Comment: Did: Thank you. That is a typos.

Comment: TheBridge:I have editted the question. You may give any conditions if needed.  Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas to solve this question?

Answer (score -2):

We can prove rigorously that $(\tau_1, \tau_2....)$ given N(t)=n is uniformly distributed in $[0,t]^n$ space.  Then the question can be solved easily.